# How Scalable is the Wave Disk Generator Engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, engines

How scalable is the wave [disk generator engine](http://www.gizmag.com/wave-disc-generator-combustion-engine/19394/)?  Are there fundamental limits to how large or small the engine can be and if so, what are they?  I'm not looking for answers addressing microscale issues, but rather, I want to know if the fluid dynamics inside the engine require a certain size range in order for the combustion to work properly.

Comment: I'll leave more informed users to say otherwise, but I'm guessing that most people won't have much experience with a brand new technology. That is unless the professor or one of his students are users here.

Comment: Let's just say there is an optimal size of the engine that maximizes output. In that case, you could probably configure multiple engines coaxially so they are turning the same, albeit larger, generator together.

Answer (score 3):

"Let me say this about that"  (extra points to those who recognize the originator of that phrase).
First:  yeah, they've invented a cool-looking device.  But, they appear to be getting nowhere so far as either advanced funding or a fieldable model produced.

Second:  I have seen at least 5 or 6 "groundbreaking new powerful/efficient/wunderdevice" internal combustion engine designs pop up over the last 30 years (not even counting the Wankel rotary).  Not one has been able to show both minimal life testing and improved efficiency over modern piston-crankshaft engines.   I see no reason to expect this design to do so either.

For further, quite specific, counterarguments, take a look at  [this review](http://newenergyandfuel.com/http:/newenergyandfuel/com/2013/09/04/arpa-e-backing-the-msu-wave-disk-engine/)

Comment: Actually it's not that these designs aren't promising, it's that the existing supply chains are so tight that getting a new design from a new company into the chain is next to impossible, no matter what the advantages.